# How to correctly implement nested generics?

Tags: java, generics

I have a property on a class that is of a type `List<List<Value>>`, and I'm trying to instantiate it with a class which is a subtype of these interfaces and classes, like so:

```
public List<List<Value>> rows = new DbRowList<MyRow>();
```

Where `DbRowList` is a type which extends `ArrayList`:

```
public class DbRowList<E extends List<Value>> extends ArrayList<E> implements List<E> {

    public boolean add(E element) {
        MyRow row = new MyRow();
        return super.add(row); // Compile-time error
    }
}
```

and `MyRow` is:

```
public class MyRow extends ArrayList<Value> implements List<Value> {
    public Table table;
}
```

Yet this won't compile because of the error present in the return statement of `DbRowList.add()`:

```
The method add(E) in the type ArrayList<E> is not applicable for the arguments (MyRow)
```

Why is it not applicable? `MyRow` extends `ArrayList<Value>` which is itself a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is self-explanatory: the compiler expects an argument of type `E` to be passed to `super.add()`.  Your code is *overriding* the `add()` method, and so has to follow suit by passing that object of type `E`.  So your code should look something like this:

```
public boolean add(E element) {
    return super.add(E); // no error here
}
```

If you are wondering how you use your class, just create the `MyRow` object outside and pass it in:

```
List<List<Value>> rows = new DbRowList<MyRow>();
MyRow row = new MyRow();
rows.add(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you do not need these all "`implements List<E>`", because `ArrayList` itself implements `List`.

Regarding to your compile-error, so it is wrong usage and understanding of generics. You will be able to add particular instance of particular class when you will specify this type variable for instance of `DbRowList` class, so this piece of code will compile and work:

```
public boolean add(E element) {
    return super.add(element); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DbRowList<MyRow>().add(new MyRow());
}
```

But if you want to force compile your example you can always make casting to generic type `E`, because generics are nothing in runtime, and lists can contain instances of any types:

```
public boolean add(E element) {
    MyRow row = new MyRow();
    return super.add((E) row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to do this?

You override method to add empty arrayList instead of actual argument value. Element is not passed anywhere.

And the reason is simple: you try to pass it to super.add which wants

```
E
```

but you pass

```
ArrayList<E>.
```

What you should do is simply not override the method but correctly define class:

```
public class DbRowList<E extends List<Value>> extends ArrayList<E>{

}

void testMethod(){
    List<List<Value>> rows = new DbRowList<>();
    rows.add(new ArrayList<>());
}
```

edit: actually, while typing I understood that it's not exactly what you want, so please clarify: do you need to save rows or save elements to specified rows? What I described is for saving whole rows but what you might need is map that points to rows. You could then add elements to specified rows without creating new row or loading/searching row you need.